# Aebacus Controls Negative Number Issue

Tags: textbox, vb6, legacy-code, negative-number

I am working to flush out some defects from an older program and I'm running into an issue with negative numbers in aebacus textboxes.

Basically, whenever a negative number (i.e. -1) is entered into a textbox, on focus lost the textbox shows the number with a trailing negative (i.e. 1-). On focus again, the number is displayed correctly as -1.

I have seen this in excel and maybe it is a formatting setting, or possibly just a limitation of vb6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using a different font can fix it, in our case we made a custom font to alleviate the issue.